# Can't find content (images/sound) when running code on another computer c++

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, sdl

I define paths to images and sound in my code with a string like this:

"Graphics\ \player.png"

I also load images through xml files and then the path looks like this:

< Graphics\tile1.png >

The graphics folder is in the project root and it works perfectly on the computer I use for developing.

If I build a release build and run it from my main computer it works properly if the Graphics folder is in the same folder as the .exe.

However, if I run the exact same thing from another computer it doesn't find any images or sound.

The dlls are probably correct, the game runs properly.

I ahve tested this on multiple computers with different specs and drivers but none work.

If I move the uncompiled source code to another computer and compile it there it works properly.

So my question is, am I missing something when I run compiled code on another computer?

Comment: `"Graphics\player.png"` is invalid as a C++ string literal.

Comment: Sorry, typo in the post. It's "\\" in c++ "\" in xml

Comment: Then I suspect that you have a different current directory when you run the program from within an IDE (Visual Studio?) as when you run it via an OS shell. Try to display your current directory path. Test in the two different situations you have.

Comment: Thanks, but it works when I run it via Windows (not visual studio) on my main computer. The folder locations are the exact same (C root).
But I'll try to display the paths, thanks again.

Comment: Actually it wasn't a typo stackover flow translates \\ to \

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using relative paths. Do you do a chdir() somewhere to the root directory from where these paths reference?

That said, you shouldn't use relative paths anywhere. Make them absolute on startup so that you never have this problem, and no (e.g.) third-party dll that calls chdir() can throw off your resource loading.

Comment: I'm not calling chdir(), should I do that?

If yes, how do I use it?

If I hardcode the absolute path, the path needs to be identical on all machines and that won't work.

Thanks,
Markus

Comment: You don't *need* to call chdir(). What you need to do is make sure that in all places where you use paths, those paths resolve to the same file on the filesystem. If you insist on using relative paths, you can do that my calling chdir() to the correct top-level directory before each time you use the path. But as you can imagine, it's very likely that you will forget at some point, and things will go wrong when somewhere else chdir is called, or the user start the program from another directory, or any of the 100's of other reasons the cwd could be wrong.

Comment: Of course you shouldn't hardcode the path. You should make the paths absolute at runtime, for example by prepending the data directory to the relative paths, either by using GetModuleFileName(), or your application's data directory from GetSpecialFolderPath(), or any other way you can resolve the name of the directory your data is stored in. So, it depends on how you organize your resources in your application on how to do it exactly.

Answer (score 1):

print out the string, try and open that exact string from the place in which you run the program from.

Not if you are running the program from the desktop or whatever the and it is try to use a path relative to it's physical location then it isn't going to work, it will use the relative path, relative to where it is run from, in this case use absolute path.